# PHP SQL PDO Wildcard query

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, sql-like

I have a table with these values:

```
123, 159, 147, 258, 369
```

I need to find the data that both includes 1 and 2 but not 3. The result should be:

```
159, 147, 258
```

I have tried the Wildcard operators % - [] and no luck.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE track LIKE '%[12]%' AND track NOT LIKE '%[3]%'";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're using works in SQL Server but not MySQL. You could use REGEXP:

```sql
WHERE track REGEXP '[12]'
AND track NOT LIKE '%3%'
```

Or just use `LIKE`:

```sql
WHERE (track LIKE '%1%' OR track LIKE '%2%')
AND track NOT LIKE '%3%'
```

Comment: This works! Thnx! But is it possible to make the "NOT LIKE" a REGEXP?

Comment: Found it out myself: 
WHERE track REGEXP '[12]' AND track NOT REGEXP '[3]'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your intent, but if you are trying to only select records that start with either 1 or 2 from a pool of 3 digit numbers, this will work.

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE track LIKE '%1[0-9][0-9]' OR track LIKE '%2[0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: The records just have to contain the numbers, not start with the numbers.